# Get Selected Item Using Checkbox in Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am creating an Android application where I have a ListView that displays all of the applications that were installed in my mobile phone.

My ListView is customized, it is contains a Icon, TextView and CheckBox, the use of the icon is to display the icon of the application, TextView is to display the name of the application, the use of the CheckBox is to determine what item in the ListView that I selected.

How can I determine what is the CheckBox that I selected in the ListView rows when I click a button in my application? I'm new in Android so I don't know what is the approach that I should do.

Here is my code:

```
public class AppInfo {
    public Drawable icon;
    public String applicationName;

    public AppInfo(){
        super();
    }

    public AppInfo(Drawable icon, String applicationName){
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }


}
```

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class AppInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppInfo> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    AppInfo  data[] = null;

    public AppInfoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, AppInfo[] data){
        super(context, layoutResourceId,data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row = convertView;
        AppInfoHolder holder= null;

        if (row == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new AppInfoHolder();

            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgPackageIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtApplicationName);
            holder.chkSelect = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chkSelect);

            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{
            holder = (AppInfoHolder)row.getTag();
        }


        AppInfo appinfo = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(appinfo.applicationName);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(appinfo.icon);
        holder.chkSelect.setChecked(true);

        return row;

    }



}
```

---

```
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class AppInfoHolder {

    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    CheckBox chkSelect;
}
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter; 
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;

public class CacheActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cache);


            final ListView listApplication = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listApplication);

            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getApplicationInfo();
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<PackageInfo> pInfo = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
            pInfo.addAll(pm.getInstalledPackages(0));
            AppInfo app_info[] = new AppInfo[pInfo.size()];

            int counter = 0;
            for(PackageInfo item: pInfo){
                try{

                    applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(item.packageName, 1);

                    app_info[counter] = new AppInfo(pm.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo), 
                            String.valueOf(pm.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo)));

                    System.out.println(counter);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                counter++;
            }

            AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, app_info);
            listApplication.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


}
```

Comment: you can sparse boolean array for this purpose.

Comment: do you want the check box checked items in the row on click of a button ? coz you title says "Get Selected Item Using Checkbox in Listview when I click a Button".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming you want to get items of row whose check boxes are checked at the click of a button. Assumption based on your title "Get Selected Item Using Checkbox in Listview when I click a Button".

Try the below. Make only changes as below. Keep the rest the same.

Explanation and discussion on the topic @

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     AppInfoAdapter adapter ;
     AppInfo app_info[] ;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            final ListView listApplication = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listApplication);
            Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i=0;i<adapter.mCheckStates.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(adapter.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                        {

                                           result.append(app_info[i].applicationName);
                            result.append("\n");
                        }

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, 1000).show();
                }

            });

            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getApplicationInfo();
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<PackageInfo> pInfo = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
            pInfo.addAll(pm.getInstalledPackages(0));
            app_info = new AppInfo[pInfo.size()];

            int counter = 0;
            for(PackageInfo item: pInfo){
                try{

                    applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(item.packageName, 1);

                    app_info[counter] = new AppInfo(pm.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo), 
                            String.valueOf(pm.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo)));

                    System.out.println(counter);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                counter++;
            }

           adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, app_info);
            listApplication.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
}
```

activity_main.xml ListView with button at the buton

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listApplication"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AppInfoAdapter

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppInfo> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates; 

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    AppInfo  data[] = null;

    public AppInfoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, AppInfo[] data){
        super(context, layoutResourceId,data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(data.length);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row = convertView;
        AppInfoHolder holder= null;

        if (row == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new AppInfoHolder();

            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.chkSelect = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{
            holder = (AppInfoHolder)row.getTag();
        }


        AppInfo appinfo = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(appinfo.applicationName);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(appinfo.icon);
       // holder.chkSelect.setChecked(true);
        holder.chkSelect.setTag(position);
        holder.chkSelect.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
        holder.chkSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        return row;

    }
    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

    }
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
        boolean isChecked) {

     mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);    

}
static class AppInfoHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    CheckBox chkSelect;

}
}
```

Here's the snap shot

[image]

Comment: Is it showing the item toast if you check only the last one ?

Comment: @RanjitPati this is a working code. there is no problem with this. If you have a problem post a new question instead of commenting. I can't guess or suggest what is wrong without seeing the code

Comment: Can you please tell where are you using `toggle`?

Comment: @Raghunandan It is not being called anywhere in the above code :)

Comment: The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type CompoundButton is not applicable for the arguments 
 (CacheBoostAdapter)   getting this error on this line deleteBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

Comment: @ErumHannan post your code by asking a separate question

Comment: @Raghunandan  i m unable to post question can u pls come in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era  and ping me i will show my code and question in pastie

Answer (score 16):

It's a simplifications but very easy...
You need to add the the focusable flag to the checkbox, as written before.
You need also to add the clickable flag, as shown here:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Than you control the checkbox state from within the `ListView` (`ListFragment` in my case) `onListItemClick` event.

This the sample onListItemClick method:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
//Get related checkbox and change flag status..
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.rowDone);
cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: in this case it disappears animation effect for Lollipop and up versions

Answer (score 9):

You have to add an OnItemClickListener to the listview to determine which item was clicked, then find the checkbox.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Provided xml sample is put as single ListViewItem, and i couldn't click on Item itself, but checkbox was workng.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/source_container"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/menu_source_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/bla"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/menu_source_name"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textScaleX="1.5"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/source_text_color"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/menu_source_check_box"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Solution: add attribute

```
android:focusable="false"
```

to CheckBox control.

Answer (score 2):

make the checkbox non-focusable, and on list-item click do this,
 here codevalue is the position.

```
    Arraylist<Integer> selectedschools=new Arraylist<Integer>();

    lvPickSchool.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
  {

   @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int codevalue, long id)
   {
                      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbVisitingStatus);

            cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
            if(cb.isChecked())
            {

                if(!selectedschool.contains(codevaule))
                {
                    selectedschool.add(codevaule);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(selectedschool.contains(codevaule))
                {
                    selectedschool.remove(codevaule);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Custom ListView with CheckBox]

If customlayout use checkbox, you must set checkbox focusable = false

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
  </TextView>

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:focusable="false">           // <---important
  </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Readmore : [A ListView with Checkboxes (Without Using ListActivity)](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php)

Answer (score 0):

**"The use of the checkbox is to determine what Item in the Listview that I selected"**

1. Just add the tag to checkbox using setTag() method in the Adapter class. and other side using getTag() method.

   ```
         @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

   ServiceHelper helper=userServices.get(position);
   holder.tvServiceName.setText(helper.getServiceName());

   if(!helper.isServiceStatus()){

       holder.btnAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       holder.btnAdd.setTag(helper.getServiceName());
       holder.checkBoxServiceStatus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

   }else{

       holder.checkBoxServiceStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          //This Line
       holder.checkBoxServiceStatus.setTag(helper.getServiceName());
       holder.btnAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

      }

   }
   ```
2. In xml  code of the checkbox just put the "android:onClick="your method""attribute.

   ```
        <CheckBox
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:onClick="checkboxClicked"  
               android:id="@+id/checkBox_Service_row"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
   ```
3. In your class Implement that method "your method".

   ```
        protected void checkboxClicked(View view)
         {

           CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) view;
             String tagName="";
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
              tagName=checkBox.getTag().toString();
              deleteServices.add(tagName);
              checkboxArrayList.add(checkBox);
           }else {
                  checkboxArrayList.remove(checkBox);
                  tagName=checkBox.getTag().toString();
                       if(deleteServices.size()>0&&deleteServices.contains(tagName)){
    deleteServices.remove(tagName);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Full reference present at : [***listview with checkbox android studio***](http://demonuts.com/2017/01/09/listview-with-checkbox-in-android-studio/)
Pass selected items to next activity

Main source code is as below.

Create a model class first

```
public class Model {

    private boolean isSelected;
    private String animal;

    public String getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(String animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

Then in adapter class, setTags to checkbox. Use those tags in onclicklistener of checkbox.

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return modelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder(); LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_item, null, true);

            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            holder.tvAnimal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.checkBox.setText("Checkbox "+position);
        holder.tvAnimal.setText(modelArrayList.get(position).getAnimal());

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(modelArrayList.get(position).getSelected());

        holder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);
        holder.checkBox.setTag( position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                View tempview = (View) holder.checkBox.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
                TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.animal); 
                Integer pos = (Integer)  holder.checkBox.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Checkbox "+pos+" clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(modelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()){
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                }else {
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        protected CheckBox checkBox;
        private TextView tvAnimal;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **model** class and use **setTag()** **getTag()** methods to keep track which items from listview are checked and which not.

More reference for this : [***listview with checkbox in android***](http://demonuts.com/2017/01/09/listview-with-checkbox-in-android-studio/)

Source code for model

```
public class Model {

    private boolean isSelected;
    private String animal;

    public String getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(String animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

put this in your custom adapter

```
 holder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);
        holder.checkBox.setTag( position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                View tempview = (View) holder.checkBox.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
                TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.animal); 
                Integer pos = (Integer)  holder.checkBox.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Checkbox "+pos+" clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(modelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()){
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                }else {
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }

            }
        });
```

whole code for customAdapter is

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return modelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder(); LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_item, null, true);

            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            holder.tvAnimal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.checkBox.setText("Checkbox "+position);
        holder.tvAnimal.setText(modelArrayList.get(position).getAnimal());

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(modelArrayList.get(position).getSelected());

        holder.checkBox.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview, convertView);
        holder.checkBox.setTag( position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                View tempview = (View) holder.checkBox.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
                TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.animal); 
                Integer pos = (Integer)  holder.checkBox.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Checkbox "+pos+" clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(modelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()){
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                }else {
                    modelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        protected CheckBox checkBox;
        private TextView tvAnimal;

    }

}
```