# Checkbox text not being retrieved

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have a `ListView` with some `CheckBoxes`.  When I click on each row of the `ListView` I want to save the `CheckBox`'s text in a `String`.

I set the `ListView` row to not focusable so that the user can click on the `CheckBox` itself.  The `CheckBox` cannot be checked or unchecked by the user himself, but instead, when the user clicks on it, he is lead to another activity where he needs to input data.  I am checking whether the user is inputing data or not by returning a boolean value.

If the value is true, I need to set the checkbox to checked.  In order to do so I need to compare the text of the `CheckBox` to another String value before actually checking it.

In other words the checked state of each `CheckBox` is determined by whether or not the user entered data in the previous activity.

What I cannot do is get the CheckBox text from the clicked/ touched/ selected `CheckBox`

Why are the below code snippets not working? `clickedError` is empty after running this code.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(final View v) 
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        clickedError = cb.getText().toString() ;
```

**AND**

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) 
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
    clickedError = cb.getText().toString() ;
}
```

**Have already been tried**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{   
        ......
        holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(holder.chk));
        ......
}


private class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    CheckBox checkbox = null;

    public MyClickListener(CheckBox cb)
    {
        checkbox = cb;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) 
    {
//          CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(mContext);
//          cb = (CheckBox) v;
//          clickedError = cb.getText().toString() ;

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        clickedError = cb.getText().toString() ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/android-get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview-when-i-click-a-button/18164177#18164177. not sure if i understand your requirement clearly

Comment: Not very clear - what text you want to return? The listview item data or the checkbox state?

Comment: Confirm which type of "View" are you getting in onClick(final View v). Is it the CheckBox you are expecting ?

Comment: The text I want to get is the text assigned to the `CheckBox`

Comment: @jagz87 It is a `CheckBox`, at least while hovering on v @ `cb = (CheckBox)` while in debugging, it shows that v is a `CheckBox`.

Comment: Well.. v.findViewById(R.id.idcheckbox) could help you!!

Comment: Yes it is a String, of course

Comment: @AntonioCalì Please be more clear.  How am I suppose to get the assigned `CheckBox` text using that?

Comment: Well I suppose your checkbox is inside a custom layout for every child of your list view, doesn't? If so, with v.findViewById you will obtain a reference to that checkbox

Comment: @AntonioCalì Yes, left it out as usual. Anyway, it is still not getting the text.  Updated original post.

Comment: @ClaireG you are creating a new checkbox object which have no text set for it so the returned string will be empty.

Comment: Whatever for ListView you should implements a AdapterView.OnItemClickListener with onItemClick method.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29

Comment: @Siddhesh You are right, but I have no other choice since `v.getText()` is not allowed.  Would you suggest anything else?

Comment: @ClaireG can you paste proper code and frame your question according to whats not working in your code so that everyone here can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ListView.onListItemClick(ListView parent, View row, int position, long id);
```

to get the reference for `CheckBox` in the list.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine. I just put down the reference and left the implementation for you to try. I'm glad that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(final View v) 
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
        clickedError = cb.getText().toString() ;
    }
```

try this.

Edit :
in your new code what are you trying to do with this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{   
        ......
        holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(holder.chk));
        ......
}
```

cant you do it like this for eg:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{   
        ......
        holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            clickedError = cb.getText().toString() ;
         }
        });
        ......
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in this line? holder.chk.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(holder.chk));

Comment: @Edit if I do that the last item in the list gets checked all the time, no matter which one I choose.  That is why I created a separate class for the OnClickListener so I can reference the `CheckBox` accordingly.