# Checkboxes in a listview: How can I trace this back to the arraylist I started from?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, arraylist

I want to create a listview with checkboxes and details, such as name and phone number. I create this (I assume) by using an arraylist or similar. In this case it will be an object, and then transfer this to each item.

Questions:

1) How can I add checkboxes to each box?

2) How should I get the original data contained back? As in if one checkbox is ticked, then how can I get the array item that corresponds to that listview item.

Comment: [ListView with CheckBox](http://venomvendor.blogspot.in/2013/12/custom-listview-with-checkbox-header.html), From one of my blog post.

Comment: Check this using SparseBooleanArray suggested by Romain Guy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/android-get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview-when-i-click-a-button