# Alert Dialog Builder wont show ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I have a class that retrieves ArrayList from Database. And I need to show this items in Alert Dialog builder. But im getting an error in this. Please Help!

Here is my error:

> Error: The method setSingleChoiceItems(int, int,
>   DialogInterface.OnClickListener) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is
>   not applicable for the arguments (Name[], int, new
>   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

```
ArrayList<Name> n_names = null;


n_names = db.getAllNames();

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Name.this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose Name");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(n_names.toArray(new Name[n_names.size()]), -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

    }});

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    }});


    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


    }});
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: what is the error can you specify?.

Comment: how you initialize your n_name here ?

Comment: i think it still null.

Comment: Error:
The method setSingleChoiceItems(int, int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (Name[], int, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: This is how I initialized n_names. This was retrieved from the database.

n_names = db.getAllNames();

Comment: @belladonna you have wrong parameters for the method that is your mistake. its int int and DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Comment: You just need to return String ArrayList from your db.getAllNames() method and convert that into String Array and bind to builder.setSingleChoiceItems(Here your String Array,checkedItem,listener)

Comment: @M D --yes I already did that--converted Arraylist to String Array
But its giving me an error:
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type com.example.name cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.CharSequence[]

Comment: Hi!Can anyone help me on how to display custom arraylist/arrayadapter in listview?Here's my code
ArrayAdapter<Name> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Name>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, n_names);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
I have no error. But it displays nothing. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is that you're providing a customized class object to the `setSingleChoiceItems` method. The first parameter has to be a a `CharSequence[]`, a `ListAdapter` or a `Cursor`. If you're not intended to put one of them, you'll have to extend the Dialog class an implement your own `setSingleChoiceItems` method.

**---- EDIT ----**

In your case, I'd recommend extending the `ArrayAdapter` class, as you have some customized structures to show (in your case, a `CheckBox`). To help you do that, you may see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096674/how-to-do-put-a-checkbox-in-a-listview/21096881#21096881) to a similar question and also a [little basic explaination](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) on how to extend the `ArrayAdapter` class, here. Hope this helps you!

Comment: but how would i do that? or can you help me implement a listview with checkbox? so that i could display the arraylist?

Comment: Hi!Can anyone help me on how to display custom arraylist/arrayadapter in listview?Here's my code ArrayAdapter<Name> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Name>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, n_names); lv.setAdapter(adapter); I have no error. But it displays nothing. please help

Comment: Seems that the datatype you're using on your ArrayAdapter is not standard (Name), so the ArrayAdapter doesn't know what to display. You should extend the ArrayAdapter class and override the getView() method in order to control what is displayed (the base class is just for standard data types).

Comment: just did! Thanks NKN!

Comment: You're welcome! if my answer helped, you should accept it so other users may find it helpful too.