# Values of checkboxes within custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I am using the following:
- I have a DialogFragment, the view contains a listview and a button
- the listview contains an imageview, a textview, and a checkbox
- I have a Custom adapter for the listview

What is need is the values of the checkboxes after I press the button in my DialogFragment view.
How do I do that? How can I access the values of the checboxes, which are only known inside my adapter (as far as I know) from outside my adapter?

Can I add a public method in my adapter, where the values of the checboxes are stored? Or is there another way?

Comment: ive edit my answer because i didnt understand your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you can do ... in your **adapter class**  create instance variable

```
SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
```

then initialize it in constructor, where **data.length** is length of values that you want to display

```
mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(data.length);
```

then you can implemented methods in your adapter like :

```
public boolean isChecked(int position) {
    return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
}

public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
    mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

}

public void toggle(int position) {
    setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

}
```

and you are good to go ... for more info you can see this link: [Get Selected Item Using Checkbox in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/android-get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview-when-i-click-a-button)