# Listview item's background selected error when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview in fragment and my problem is when I select items on listview then it's fine, but when I scroll my listview then item's background is checked for another items, but I don't want that. You can see my image, first I select 3 items (Browser, Calendar, Contact), when I scroll listview then 2 items (Dev tool, Camera) have a changed background, if I continue scroll then listview has more items like that.

[image]
    [image]

Here is my code:

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class Tab2 extends Fragment{
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    public static ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;
    public static ListView list;
    private ActionMode acMode;
    private int counterChecked = 0;
    private SparseBooleanArray sp;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2test,container,false);
        list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_view2);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);
        list.setAdapter(listadaptor);
        sp = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //Here i set item's color and unselected color
                view.setBackgroundColor(sp.get(position)? 0x9934B5E4: Color.WHITE);
                if(counterChecked<1){
                    acMode = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                }
                String str="";
                int i=0;
                for(i=0;i<sp.size();i++)
                {   
                    if(sp.valueAt(i)){
                        str+=sp.keyAt(i)+",";

                    }
                }

                if(list.isItemChecked(position)){
                    Log.d("list1", String.valueOf(position));
                    list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    counterChecked++;
                }else{
                    list.setItemChecked(position, false);
                    counterChecked--;
                }

                if(counterChecked<1){
                    mActionModeCallback.onDestroyActionMode(acMode);

                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if(isSystemPackage(info)){
                    if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                        applist.add(info);
                    }                   
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return applist;
    }

    private boolean isSystemPackage(ApplicationInfo AInfo) {
        return ((AInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback(){

        @Override 
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
              MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
              inflater.inflate(R.menu.cab_menu, menu);
              MainActivity.toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              return true;
            }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mode.finish();
            MainActivity.toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually trigger `OnItemClickListener` when scrolling which causes a multiple select for items that you didn't want to include.

A better approach would be using a `checkBox` inside your `listView` Item and mark the item as selected when the check box is checked: check out this [link on how to Get Selected Item Using Checkbox in Listview.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview)

If you incest on using `onClick` then you can implement `longClickListener` on your `listView` Items which may prevent get item selected when scrolling but my advice to you is to go with `checkBoxes`.

**`OnLongClickListener` Implementation:**

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                    int index, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 String str=listView.getItemAtPosition(index).toString();


                return true;
            }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try using checkBoxes