# Find the selected check boxes in a list view Android

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a project and in that I want to get the track of items that are selected (check box) from a list view.
Is there any way of doing it?
Code so far is below;

**Main Activity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    Model[] modelItems;
    CheckBox ONE,TWO,THREE;
    Button MultiData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        modelItems = new Model[5];
        modelItems[0] = new Model("pizza", 0);
        modelItems[1] = new Model("burger", 0);
        modelItems[2] = new Model("olives", 0);
        modelItems[3] = new Model("orange", 0);
        modelItems[4] = new Model("tomato", 0);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Model[] modelItems = null;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Model[] resource) {
        super(context, R.layout.row1, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.modelItems = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());
        if (modelItems[position].getValue() == 1)
            cb.setChecked(true);
        else
            cb.setChecked(false);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Model{
    String name;
    int value; /* 0 -&gt; checkbox disable, 1 -&gt; checkbox enable */

    Model(String name, int value){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

**main_xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**row1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Eidt1 in Main Activity**

```
boolean modelItemBool[] = new boolean[modelItems.length];
        for (int h =0;h<modelItemBool.length;h++){
            modelItemBool[h] = false;
        }
```

**Eidt 2**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
          CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()  {
              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                  if(isChecked){
                      modelItems[position].getValue() == 1;
                  }else{
                      modelItems[position].getValue() == 0;
                  }
              }
          });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you have to record the checked positions once they get checked, in the listener. You can't get all the views from the ListView since they are being reused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Selected Item Using Checkbox in Listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview)

Comment: @VladMatvienko How can I `record the checked positions once they get checked`?

Comment: try using vewHolder as @ShabbirDhangot

Comment: add a checked listener to the checkbox, in that listener store if checkbox is checked in some list in Adapter. Once you need the list of checked - get the list.

Comment: you want a list contains all the selected items?

Comment: @xiaoyuan How can I get the list and positions of selected items?

Comment: @xiaoyuan See the edit1 in question.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Kindly show the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

create Boolean array same as your **modelItems** size and store true false value in that array

**Step 1 :** by default store all value false in array

**Step 2 :** update value in array on checkbox check state change

Comment: I have added this `boolean modelItemBool[] = new boolean[modelItems.length];
        for (int h =0;h<modelItemBool.length;h++){
            modelItemBool[h] = false;
        }`

Comment: @Mahul Gajjar How can I implement Step2?

Answer (score 0):

- new a list to keep selected items:

  ```
  List<Model> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();

  private List getSelectedList(){
      if(!selectedList.isEmpty()) selectedList.clear();
      for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          if(modelItems [i].getValue==1){
              selectedList.add(modelItems [i]);
          }
      }
      return selectedList;
  }
  ```
- set `onCheckedChangeListener` for `CheckBox` in `getView`:

  ```
   cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()  {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if(isChecked){
                 modelItems[position].setValue(1); 
              }else{
                  modelItems[position].setValue(0); 
              }
          }
      });
  ```

Comment: Add the first step to `MainActivity`,and the second to `getView` method in Adapter. When ever you want the selectedList just call the method `getSelectedList()`.

Comment: I have added the step2 in `getView` and change the `position` to final as suggested by android. But it gives the error on line `modelItems[position].getValue() == 1;` See the edit 2 in question

Comment: What is `array` in step1?

Comment: It's an easier way like `Model[] modelItems`. see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: What is `array` ? Is it has anything in it? Would you like to make the full code and show the whole class code ?

Comment: Do you mean `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below before return convertView; then modelItems array will be updated every time a checkbox is checked/unchecked

```
  final int posFinal = position;
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                modelItems[posFinal].setValue( b ? 1 : 0); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: `modelItems[posFinal].getValue()` returns integer.~ ~

Comment: modelItems[posFinal].setValue( b ? 1 : 0);

Comment: @Tonteria24 How can I get the modelItems array in MainActivty on button click? I need it in the MainActivity.

Comment: When you called the CustomAdapter constructor you passed the array (you passed a reference to the array) as parameter, the changes you make to modelItems in the Adapter will also be made in Activity modelItems, both are the same array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replace your code with bellow, on the click of button it will show selected checkbox name in alert dialog.
// MainActivity 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    Model[] modelItems;
    Button btn;
    String selectedCheckBoxNAme = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_xml);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn) ;
        modelItems = new Model[5];
        modelItems[0] = new Model("pizza", 0);
        modelItems[1] = new Model("burger", 0);
        modelItems[2] = new Model("olives", 0);
        modelItems[3] = new Model("orange", 0);
        modelItems[4] = new Model("tomato", 0);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedCheckBoxNAme = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < modelItems.length; i++) {
                    Model obj= modelItems [i];
                    if(obj.getValue() == 1)
                    {
                        selectedCheckBoxNAme = selectedCheckBoxNAme +"\n" + obj.getName();
                    }
                }
                if(!selectedCheckBoxNAme.isEmpty()) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity4.this).setTitle("").setMessage(selectedCheckBoxNAme)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                }
                            })
                            .setCancelable(false).create().show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
// CustomAdapter.java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Model[] modelItems = null;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Model[] resource) {
        super(context, R.layout.row1, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.modelItems = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());
        if (modelItems[position].getValue() == 1)
            cb.setChecked(true);
        else
            cb.setChecked(false);

        cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
             modelItems[position].setValue(1);
            }else{
             modelItems[position].setValue(0);
            }
        }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
//main_xml.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Here"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

// Model 
public class Model {
    String name;
    int value; /* 0 -&gt; checkbox disable, 1 -&gt; checkbox enable */

    Model(String name, int value){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```