# Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am creating an app in which I can search for files and delete it.

```
    searchstring = receivedmsg.getString("mysearch");
    tv.setText("Search Results for " + searchstring);   

    searchForFileNameContainingSubstring(searchstring);

    //ListAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resList);
    //lv.setAdapter(myadapter);

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(DataFetcher.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , resList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Searched results are showing in `listview`. How can I add checkboxes in `listview`?

Already searched on google but it's not working. How can I achieve that?

Comment: check this [link](https://www.journaldev.com/14171/android-checkbox)

Comment: You've to create custom single list layout for adding checkbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Selected Item Using Checkbox in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview)

Answer (score 2):

Create custom layout with any name you want:
for example:

**single_item_list.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dip" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your `customAdapter`:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(DataFetcher.this, R.layout.single_item_list , resList);
```

and handle functionalities in `customAdapter`