# try to display button with toast function in my ListView

Tags: java, android, button, toast

How to and where to add `button` with Toast `function` in my `application`.

I know many time this question is asked but still, I am confused so can anyone help.

[Text]

[Button 1] [Button 2]

[Text]

[Button 1][Button 2]

Here is my code :

```
public class EngineerRecycler extends AppCompatActivity {
String service_id,type, jsonStr;
String compticketid;
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String urlpending = "http://localhost/players.php";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_engineer_recycler );
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    service_id = bundle.getString( "empid" );
    type = bundle.getString( "type" );
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to URL and getting a response

            jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall( urlpending, service_id );

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString("ClientName");
                    String email = c.getString("comp_desc");


                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("ClientName", name);
                    contact.put("comp_desc", email);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);



            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    EngineerRecycler.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_pending, new String[]{"ClientName", "comp_desc"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.email);

            lv.setAdapter( adapter );

        }
    }
    }
}
```

I am able to display the items in `listview` but when now I want to add `button` to it.

that too whenever I click on it `toast` message should pop.

Here is XML file

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="351dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Reached" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are very unclear what are you asking.

Comment: In short how to add button in my listview

Comment: You want a button as separate item. Or you want button make visible in existing item?

Comment: make visible in existing item 
But with toast function

Comment: you need to create a custom row (xml file) and design it as you like (Text + Button) and apply it to your Listview... there are many examples in the internet on how to do that.

Comment: You can create CustomAdapter for it and use RecyclerView intsead of ListView.

Comment: On internet i am not getting it exactly what should i do and I am new to android studio so that a problem - @user007

Comment: Can you tell what exact changes should i make in current code - @ParasVerma

Comment: just add button with toast function - @ParasVerma

Comment: @nikhillohar Update your `list_pending.xml` code.

Comment: i have updated my xml file - @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: Already you have the button in layout so buttons not visible or you need click functionality for buttons.

Comment: Exactly i need click function for buttons - @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: Add click method of button in your adapter class.

Comment: Simple adapter is your own class or predefined class?

Comment: Is my own class and  can you please tell me what exactly I have to do  - @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: You have to implement getView() method

Comment: You see i am new to coding so can you tell how to do it - @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: Update your adapter code pls

Comment: Thats my updated code only In this file i have done all this things except the connection part - @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: This is what am asking SimpleAdapter is android class. So you can override listview setonitemclicklistener method. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            //You can find your button here
           if(view instanceof Button)
            {
                if(view.getId() == R.id.getenter)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"toast_msg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

after adapter code.

```
lv.setadapter(adpater);
```

Comment: After as in 
after lv.setadapter(adpater); 
i have to write setonItemClickListerner(); - @Mohamed Mohaideen

Comment: Yes you have to add this method after setadapter and find anyviews inside that method from the class `list_pending`.. and perform action.

Comment: I have copy paste the same code but no toast message shown

Comment: You can put breakpoints & check the condtions of if loop are ok.

Comment: Actually the button is not working only I tried putting something else

Comment: `button is not working` - i can't get you.. Without the if loop you can able to show toast or not? Check with that..

Comment: I am saying that i guess the IF cases are not working

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow.

After knowing about your requirement. Here is the solution.

> First take a boolean in your model class.

```
class Model {
  boolean buttonVisible;
  // settter getter
}
```

> Now attach this boolean value to your button visibility in your adapter `getView()`.

```
holder.button.setVisibility(model.isButtonVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

> Now when you want to change a button visible. Just change this boolean
>   and notify list for data change.

```
yourList.get(2).setButtonVisible(true);
((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

> This will make the 2 index button visible. If you are confused
>   anywhere, please ask me.

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18164177/6891563)** is related to your question. Just the difference is- In this answer this guy is attaching CheckBox to Model. And you will attach visibility to Mode.

#### Suggestion

Use **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)**, because that has lot of performance considering feature.

Like `notifyItemDataChanged()` to notify only item which is changed, whether in ListView all the items would be nofified.